# WPF UserControl background Transparency doesn't work

Tags: wpf, user-controls, transparency

I try to pop up a usercontrol using own class ModalDialogManager : Control  but the background doesn't seem transparent as shown on http://prntscr.com/6cgyc2
in my ModalDialogManager class, I did specify the windows to allow transparency:

```
        Window w = new Window();
        m_window = w;
        w.Closing += w_Closing;
        w.Owner = GetParentWindow(this);
        w.DataContext = this.DataContext;
        w.SetBinding(Window.ContentProperty, "");
        w.Title = Title;
        w.Icon = Icon;
        w.Height = DialogHeight;
        w.Width = DialogWidth;
        w.ResizeMode = DialogResizeMode;
        // SHOULD IT WORK?!
        w.AllowsTransparency = true;

        double t = GetParentWindow(this).Left;
        if (IsBorderless)
        {
            w.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            w.ShowInTaskbar = false;

            if (IsStartUpLocationCenter)
            {
                w.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            }
            else
            {
                w.Left = LeftPosition;
                w.Top = RightPosition;
                w.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            w.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        }
        if (IsModal)
            w.ShowDialog();
        else
            w.Show();
```

but the UserControl design shows ok: http://prntscr.com/6cgyz8

Thus, I tried to use a window to attach the usercontrol and do window.showDialog() with a usercontrol as below:

```
                Window w = new Window();
                SolidColorBrush b = new SolidColorBrush();
                b.Color = .Colors.Transparent;
                w.Background = b;
                Grid g = new Grid();
                g.Children.Add(new ucSelectCloth());
                w.Content = g;
                g.Background = b;
                w.Height = 300;
                w.Width = 600;
                w.ShowDialog();
```

As you can see that http://prntscr.com/6cgzdk the window doesn't look Transparent too.

Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

window remains opaque until you set [Window.AllowsTransparency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to true. Once you set `Window.AllowsTransparency` to `true` you have to set WindowStyle to None.

add following lines to your code,

```
w.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
w.AllowsTransparency = true;
```

Comment: Hi Chatux, I'm sorry that the code was incomplete. the window version works well, just the class that contains the user control doesn't. May I know why?